# How to store value from Drop Down List In Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, mysql-insert-id

I have created a Dynamic Drop Down list which is populating data from database. Till now its working fine. Now I want to add the selected data from drop down list into my Database. I have tried various possible methods but unable to insert values in my database, following program is not given any error message but it is also not inserting data in my database. Kindly check it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php 

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{


    include 'connect.php';

            $select_query=          'Select * from category';
            $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);

    echo "  
        <form action='insert_product.php' method='POST' ></br>

        Product Name:   <input type='text' name='product_name'  /></br>

        Price       :   <input type= 'text' name= 'price'  /></br>

        Description :   <input type='text' name='description'  />*Seperate by Comma</br>

                        ";



    //  Drop Down Display   




            echo "<select name='category'>";


            while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
            {

                    echo "<option value='".$select_query_array['category_id']."' >".
                    htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"])."</option>";


                }

         $selectTag= "<input type='submit' value='Insert'  /></select></form>";

         echo $selectTag;
    //Drop Down End!




    if(isset($_POST['product_name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])  )
    {
        echo $product_name  =       $_POST['product_name'];
        echo $price         =       $_POST['price'];
        echo $description   =       $_POST['description'];
        echo $category      =       $_POST['category'];


//Problem Area 

    $query= "insert into products (name, price, description,  category_id ) 
                VALUES( '$product_name', $price, '$description', $category )";


    if($query_run=      mysql_query($query))
    {

        echo 'Data Inserted';



        }   
        else
        {
            'Error In SQL'.mysql_error();
            }
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'empty Field';
        }

}

else
{
    echo 'You Must Log in To View this Page!';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should get it like a $_POST... `$category = $_POST['category']; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$select_query=          'Select * from category';
$select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);
echo "  
    <form action='insert_product.php' method='POST' ></br>

    Product Name:   <input type='text' name='product_name'  /></br>

    Price       :   <input type= 'text' name= 'price'  /></br>

    Description :   <input type='text' name='description'  />*Seperate by Comma</br>

                    <input type='submit' value='Insert'  />";
echo "<select name='category'>";
while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
        {

                echo "<option value='".$select_query_array['category_id']."' >".
                htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"])."</option>";


            }

echo "</select></form>";
```

The query:

```
$query= "insert into products (name, price, description, category_id, name) VALUES('$product_name', $price, '$description', '".$_POST['category']."' )";
```

Comment: Its giving an error message. Notice: Undefined index: category in F:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\insert_product.php on line 74

Comment: Its not giving any error message but also its not inserting the records.

Comment: On the page `insert_product.php` write `print_r($_POST);die;` and see what `post variables` you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I  think that ,you have to use as a post "category" and not the value of the Option
Es.

```
$category = $_POST['category']);
nsert into products (name, price, description, category_id, name) 
                VALUES('$product_name', $price, '$description', '$category"' )";
```